Trim Java Playwright dependency size
I wrote a small app that opens my chrome browser, fills in a form, submits and then takes a print screen of the final web page.
Playwright works perfectly for this, but the fact that seems to add about 170mb to my jar is making my pipelines struggle.
It seems like in the dependency there are some binaries that I might not need, since I am not using Playwright browsers, this is how Im using Playwright:
public void processHtml(String url) {
    Map<String,String> env = new HashMap<>();
    env.put("PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD","1");
    Playwright playwright = Playwright.create(new Playwright.CreateOptions().setEnv(env));
    BrowserType chromium = playwright.chromium();
    Browser browser = chromium.launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions()
            .setExecutablePath(Path.of(ChromePathFinder.getChromeExecutablePath())));
    Page page = browser.newPage();
    page.navigate(url);
    page.fill("input#textbox", "Test Input");
    page.check("input[name='radio'][value='option1']");
    page.selectOption("select#combobox", "option2");
    page.click("button[type='submit']");
    page.waitForLoadState();
    String screenshotPath = "screenshot.png";
    page.screenshot(new Page.ScreenshotOptions().setPath(Paths.get(screenshotPath)));
    browser.close();
    playwright.close();
}

and my POM looks like this:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>..</groupId>
<artifactId>..</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>..</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.playwright</groupId>
        <artifactId>playwright</artifactId>
        <version>1.49.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

can someone tell me how can I make my jar lighter ? Thanks

Do you really need Spring Boot ? Or even Spring ?

Hi Steward, yes I do. Also thats not the main issue here, I’m interested in trimming down this 170mb. I’m not too worried about the other 20-30mb

What other 20-30mb?  I think you have not supplied all the information.

Before adding this dependency, the jar was 30mb, now is 200+. So this dependency added about 170mb. I’m not worried about the 30, I want to trim the new dependency

Ah, that makes more sense now. Use the command mvn dependency:tree to analyse what it is pulling in.
